# How to set selected DataGrid rows columns border color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am in the proccess of making some `Style` resources to be aplied to all datagrids I need this formatting on, but no matter what I try I can't seem to find what will allow me to set the `DataGrid` selected row's borders to Transparent?

This is the XAML so far,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light" />
       <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And this is the result,

[image]

How do I set the selected columns boarders to transparent? What `Trigger Property` do I need to use and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are looking for this:

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
```

Comment: That turns off the rows borders as well, I was wanting to keep those black.

Comment: Have you choosed style target type  "DataGridCell" ?

Comment: Ok, i think you should set DataGridCell BorderThickness to "0,1,0,1" (left, top, right, bottom)